# Android BLE: onCharacteristicRead() appears to be blocked by thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I'm implementing a series of characteristic reads against a BLE device.  Because `readCharacteristic()` executes asynchronously, and because we have to wait until it completes before issuing another "read" call, I used a lock to `wait()` and then in `'onCharacteristicRead()` I `notify()` the lock to get things going again.

When I `wait()` after calling `readCharacteristic()`, I never get a call to `onCharacteristicRead()`.  If I don't `wait()`, then I do get a call to `onCharacteristicRead()` and the correct value is reported.

Here is the relevant code that seems to block the callback to `onCharacteristicRead()`:

```
private void doRead() {
    //....internal accounting stuff up here....
    characteristic = mGatt.getService(mCurrServiceUUID).getCharacteristic(mCurrCharacteristicUUID);
    isReading = mGatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);

    showToast("Is reading in progress? " + isReading);

    showToast("On thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

    // Wait for read to complete before continuing.
    while (isReading) {
        synchronized (readLock) {
            try {
                readLock.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
    showToast("onCharacteristicRead()");
    showToast("On thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

    byte[] value = characteristic.getValue();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : value) {
        sb.append(String.format("%02X", b));
    }

    showToast("Read characteristic value: " + sb.toString());

    synchronized (readLock) {
        isReading = false;
        readLock.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

If I simply remove the `while()` statement above, I successfully get the read callback.  Of course, that prevents me from waiting to do further reads, so I can't move forward without waiting.

Given that the `readCharacteristic()` is asynchronous, why would execution of the calling thread have anything to do with the ability to actually do the read, or the ability to call the callback?

To make things more confusing, I show a toast which identifies the thread when I call `readCharacteristic()`, as well as when `onCharacteristicRead()` is invoked.  These 2 threads have different names.  I thought that maybe the callback was being invoked on the calling thread for some reason, but that doesn't appear to be the case.  So what is going on here with the threading?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem here appears to be an obscure issue with threading and it can't be seen in my original post because I didn't post enough of the call history to see it.  I will explain what I found here in case it effects someone else.

The full call history leading to my problem went something like this:

1. Start Le Scan
2. Find device I care about
3. Connect to the device's GATT server (which returns a GATT client, and where I provide a BluetoothGattCallback for all the async communication calls)
4. Tell the GATT client to `discoverServices()`
5. A moment later, the BLE system invokes my callback's `onServicesDiscovered()`
6. Now I'm ready to start reading characteristics because the service data is loaded, so this is where I invoke that `doRead()` method in my original post
7. Tell the GATT client to `readCharacteristic()`
8. Go to sleep until the read is done
   ---- This is where deadlock occurs, but its supposed to:
9. A moment later, the BLE system invokes my callbacck's `onCharacteristicRead()`
10. Notify all waiting threads
11. Go back to step 7 and repeat

**First Mistake:**

Originally my `onServicesDiscovered()` method looked like this:

```
public void onServicesDiscovered(final BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
    doRead();
}
```

When `doRead()` executes, it is going to sleep and therefore block execution.  This prevents the callback method from finishing and apparently gunks up the entire BLE communicaiton system.

**Second Mistake:**

Once I realized the above issue, I changed the method to the following:

```
public void onServicesDiscovered(final BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            doRead();
        }
    ).start();
}
```

As far as I can tell, the above version of the method should work.  I'm creating a new thread on which to run `doRead()`, so sleeping in `doRead()` should not have any impact on the BLE thread.  **But it does!**  This change had no impact.

----------- Edit Note --------------

After posting this, I really couldn't rationalize why the above anonymous thread wouldn't work.  So I tried it again, and this time it **did work**.  Not sure what went wrong the first time, maybe I forgot to call `start()` on the thread or something...

--------- End Edit Note ------------

**The Solution:**

Finally, on a whim, I decided to create a background `HandlerThread` when my class gets instantiated (instead of spinning up an anonymous `Thread` in `onServicesDiscovered()`).  The method now looks like this:

```
public void onServicesDiscovered(final BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
    mBackgroundHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            doRead();
        }
    ).start();
}
```

The above version of the method works.  The call to `doRead()` successfully iterates over each characteristic as the previous one is read.

Comment: Can you please provide the complete source for the class ? I am also facing a similar problem . Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is your `mBackgroundHandler` get initialized?

Comment: Noticed the same thing!. When debugging and breaking on on writeCharacteristic() it always seemed to work. I guess this is synchronization issue.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this problem by adding the following code

```
        @Override
    public void onCharacteristicWrite(final BluetoothGatt gatt, final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
        super.onCharacteristicWrite(gatt, characteristic, status);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                gatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
            }
        }).start();
    }
```